# Preventing Devise from sending an email when changing password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise with my Rails 3 application. The current behavior for resetting a password, is to click on the "Forgot your password?" link. The link here is:

```
(url)/password/new.user
```

Which will call the following method in the Devise passwords_controller.rb:

```
def new
    build_resource({})
end
```

This method will do:

1. generates the password reset token and adds it to the database,
2. sends an email to the person with a link that includes the token:

   (url)/password/edit?reset_password_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Is there any way to convince Devise to perform step 1 ONLY and not step 2? Are there any security issues I should be aware of if this is possible, and I did take this approach in an effort to simplify a portion of the web site.

Comment: Is your question whether you can stop devise from sending the link *in code*, or as a result of some malformed request from a client?

Comment: You could pull the gem into your vendor/cache and modify the code there. This would allow you to change how devise handles the build_resource method.

Comment: To Kobaltz: Yes, I can pull the gem in and modify it, but that's not what I'm after.

Comment: To Chris Cashwell: Neither. I want it NOT to send the email. Please read the question.

Comment: see https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4526

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend overriding `send_devise_notification` on your User (?) model and return true when the notification value is `:reset_password_instructions`. Something like this:

```
# app/models/user.rb
def send_devise_notification(notification)
    return true if notification == :reset_password_instructions
end
```

Check their example on how to override/customize behavior for sending emails
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L127

Answer (score 7):

The title of the question is general, but the question itself is more specific.  This is the answer to the general question as of 2021.

To prevent a password changed email notification from being sent when changing a user password, call `skip_password_change_notification!` on the user **before saving** the user.

```
user = User.find(123)
user.skip_password_change_notification!
user.password = 'DoNotUse$123'
user.save
```

Answer (score 3):

You can disable it at instance level:

```
# disable all notifications
user.define_singleton_method(:send_devise_notification) { |*_| true }

# disable the one you want
user.define_singleton_method(:send_devise_notification) do |*args|
  return true if args[0] == :reset_password_instructions
  super
end
```

Comment: Perfect solution for scripts! Thanks @fabriciofreitag!!!